# Whatever happened to plumbas?

Tags: history, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, poultry

Not so many years ago, a [plumba](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/82677/jewish/Buying-Kosher-Meat-Fowl.htm) ([apparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Joseph#Successes) created by [Rabbi Jacob Joseph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Joseph)) -- a metal tag attached to the wing of a kosher chicken indicating that it was, indeed, kosher -- on a kosher chicken was the norm.  Now I hardly ever see them.  Where did they go?  Why did the rabbis stop requiring that plumbas be attached to kosher chickens?  Is there some other sign that we can rely upon?

Comment: I'm guessing the distribution practices changed and a religious Jew is in the truck.

Comment: what language is plumba? I always wondered.

Comment: @Menachem I'd guess Yiddish, but I don't speak the language so can't know for sure.

Comment: @DannySchoemann There is an old joke from the Catskills Jewish resorts where a guest complained that his wife nearly choked on a plumba, and that he would sue the resort for all its worth.  The owner got on the microphone and said: "I'd like to announce that Mrs. Goldberg has found the hidden plumba and won a free week at the resort."

Comment: Maybe sanity returned and plumba users realized that God is probably concerned with less picayune matters than whether a bird is kosher or not?

Comment: Plumbas used to be made out of lead which is plumb in Greek like the periodic symbol Pb. See http://www.bagseals.org/gallery/main.php?g2_itemId=4624

Comment: @Menachem from Latin of lead. Pb is the symbol for lead. See http://he.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%94

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Forward.com [reported](http://forward.com/articles/9003/kosher-goes-high-tech-in-fraud-fight/) (2006) that plumbas were being replaced with holograms to fight fraud.

Comment: So where are the holograms?

Comment: @user6591, on the packages.

Answer (score 1):

> Where did they go? Why did the rabbis stop requiring that plumbas be attached to kosher chickens?

According to [Wikipedia](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3_%28%D7%91%D7%93%22%D7%A5%29#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.A0.D7.99_.D7.9B.D7.A9.D7.A8.D7.95.D7.AA_.D7.94.D7.91.D7.93.22.D7.A6) , the use of Plumbas is illegal. The Israeli Ministry of Health outlawed them after an 8 month old child swallowed one, in June 2007 (As [reported by בחדרי חרדים](http://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=2229327&forum_id=3845)).

> Is there some other sign that we can rely upon?

Nowadays they use holograms.